# Where should I ask a question about cognitive biases?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Where should I ask a question about cognitive biases?

In the absence of a Stack Exchange site about logic, would Skeptics be the place for it?

Comment: What impulse led you to think that stackoverflow was a good place to start?

Comment: @AlexBrown not certain if this is an honest-to-God question or a playful one? In any case, the StackExchange network of sites is a great place to answer Q&As in a rational way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Cognitive Sciences](http://cogsci.stackexchange.com) seems a reasonable place to start. [Psychology questions](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) are on-topic there which is where cognitive biases are often studied.

It has a [bias](/questions/tagged/bias) tag which seems to have [pretty much the definition you are looking for](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bias), and a even a [cognitive-bias](/questions/tagged/cognitive-bias) tag which is a synonym of the aforementioned [bias](/questions/tagged/bias) tag.